# unexpected behavior with normalize_token

Tags: python, dask

I am getting unexpected behavior with the following test. It is likely I may have misunderstood something but currently I'm out of ideas and would appreciate input. Consider the following test:

```
# test passing an object
from dask import delayed, compute, get, set_options
# for testing the caching
from dask.base import normalize_token
from dask.cache import Cache

set_options(delayed_pure=True)


def test_object_hash():
    cache_tmp = cache.Cache(1e9)
    # test that object hashing is working
    class Foo:
        a = 1
        b = 2

    @normalize_token.register(Foo)
    def tokenize_foo(self):
        return normalize_token((self.a, self.b))

    global_list = list()

    def add(foo):
        print("here")
        global_list.append(1)
        return foo.a + foo.b

    # first, verify the hashes are the same
    myobj = Foo()
    first = delayed(add)(myobj)
    myobj2 = Foo()
    second = delayed(add)(myobj2)
    assert first.key == second.key

    # don't test with streams since it should be the same result
    # this better highlights the problem
    compute(first, get=get)
    compute(second, get=get)
    assert global_list == [1]
```

The first assert statement passes, but the second does not. I thought that dask cached the result so that computations with the same dask key are only computed once. Is there something missing in this code?
Note this has been working in `dask.distributed` so this is likely a misunderstanding in the API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question. I had not registered the cache properly. I had to add the line:
    cache.register()

If anyone has additional comments about this though I'm happy to hear. thanks.